# How do I use preg_match_all with 2 values and preg_replace to create 2 different links

Tags: php, preg-replace, hyperlink, preg-match-all

I have a text file that I am displaying in a table. I am using preg_match_all to find a specific Title with a specific Chapter and I am replacing the Title and Chapter with preg_replace to make it a link..

For example the contents within the text file are as follows:

```
Dec 04 20:15 Naruto 123
Dec 04 17:42 Naruto 98
Dec 04 16:19 D Gray Man 001
Dec 04 16:05 Bleach 128
Dec 04 12:13 50 x 50 44
```

And I am replacing the Title's and Chapters... (i.e. Naruto 123) with a link to the webpage where that is located.

I also need to take into effect the folderpath that the webpage is located in.

- The folderpath is the title of the anime. So if we were doing it for Naruto 123 the folder path is Naruto/.

So in the end the link will look like this:

```
http://website/folderpath/animetitle animechapter
```

The problem that I have is that I can get the folderpath's correct but I cannot create 2 or more distinct links. My code replaces Naruto 123 and Naruto 98 with the same link.

Here is what my code:

```
  <?

  $data=file_get_contents('series-updates.txt'); //get data from file

$regexp[0]="/(Naruto)[[:space:]](\w+)/";

$regexp[1]="/Naruto/";

preg_match($regexp[0], $data, $matches); //match Manga Title with Chapter for URL

$url= $matches[0];

preg_match($regexp[1], $data, $matches2); //match Manga Title for folderpath

$folderpath= $matches2[0];

$patterns= '/(Naruto)[[:space:]](\w+)/';

$replacements= '<a href="'.$folderpath.'/'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';

$data=preg_replace($patterns,$replacements, $data);

  $dat=explode("\n",$data); //split data at new lines

  echo '<table cellspacing=0>';

  foreach ($dat AS $value) { //loop

echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';

  }

  echo '</table>';

  ?>
```

here is an the output of the code:

```
http://xennetworks.com/output3.php
```

** ALSO, the reason why in the php code I am using preg_match instead of preg_match_all is because if I use preg_match_all for the links I get the output of ARRAY and I wanted you to see the outcome that I would like.

Comment: Do you want the script to be limited to one specific title (Naruto in your example) and ignore all other lines? If not, what is the expected result for the last three lines (having no chapter number)?

Comment: In the end it is not supposed to be limited to one title. 

The last three lines are going to have chapter numbers I just forgot to add them in. I will do so. 

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size though I'm not sure what you're looking for the link URL:

```
$s= <<<STR
Dec 04 20:15 Naruto 123
Dec 04 17:42 Naruto 98
Dec 04 16:19 D Gray Man 001
Dec 04 16:05 Bleach 128
Dec 04 12:13 50 x 50 44
STR;

preg_match_all('/\w{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s(.+)?\s(\d{2,})/', $s, $m);

for ($i=0; $i<count($m[1]); $i++) {
 $url= sprintf('http://xennetworks.com/%s %s', $m[1][$i], $m[2][$i]);
 echo("$url\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm playing with what you gave me.. but in the meantime...

The like link should look like this: http://xennetworks.com/output3.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$filedata = "Dec 04 20:15 Naruto 123
Dec 04 17:42 Naruto 98
Dec 04 16:19 D Gray Man 001
Dec 04 16:05 Bleach 128
Dec 04 12:13 50 x 50 44";

$lines = explode("\n", $filedata);

echo "<table border=\"1\">";

foreach($lines as $line)
{
echo "<tr>";
preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s(.+?)\s(\d+)\s*?$/", $line, $matches);
echo "<td>$matches[1]</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"/$matches[2]/$matches[2] $matches[3]\">$matches[2] $matches[3]</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
?>
```